# Eigen: How to extract a row from a Sparse Matrix in an Array

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a Sparse matrix and I would like to initialize an Array from it.

Is there something better and more "compact" than a for cycle? I'm looking for something like:

```
SparseMatrix<float, RowMajor> SpM;
ArrayXf Af;
Af = Arrayf(SpM.row(1));
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Row of non-zero elements?

Comment: It is supposed to be initialized,the actual values aren't the point.
I can edit the question if can be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is almost correct. The only subtle difference to make it work is to first construct a dense VectorXf before moving to the array world:

```
SparseMatrix<float,RowMajor> mat;
ArrayXf Af;
Af = VectorXf(mat.row(1));
```